# EF Core 6 one-to-many to TPH entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to implement an EF Core 6 one-to-many relationship where the 'many' side is to the child object in a TPH entity model.  For some reason, I can't get the 'one side' navigation property to be accepted.

I keep getting this error:

> The [InverseProperty] attribute on property 'MapQuestions.Map' is not valid.
> The property 'MapQuestions' is not a valid navigation on the related type 'Maps'.
> Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation.

`MapQuestions` is defined on the one-side, so I'm wondering if I'm missing a convention for the relationship to be picked up.

Here are my entities:

```
[Table("maps")]
public partial class Maps
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<MapQuestion> MapQuestions { get; set; }
}

[Table("Questions")]
public abstract class Question
{
  ...
  [Required]
  [Column("imageable_type")]
  public string ImageableType { get; set; } // discriminator
}

public class MapQuestion : Question
{
  ...
  // [ForeignKey(nameof(MapId))]
  // [InverseProperty(nameof(Maps.MapQuestions))]
  public virtual Maps Map { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [Column("imageable_id"]
  public uint MapId { get; set; }
}
```

And in my model creating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
          .HasDiscriminator(x => x.ImageableType)
          .HasValue<MapQuestion>("MapQuestions");

  /*
  modelBuilder.Entity<MapQuestion>(entity =>
  {
    entity
      .HasOne(d => d.Map)
      .WithMany(p => p.MapQuestions)
      .HasForeignKey(d => d.MapId)
      .IsRequired();
  });
  */
}
```

Everything compiles, it's at run-time that the exception is thrown. I can successfully query `MapQuestions` entity directly using the `dbcontext`, so it appears TPH is defined properly.

Comment: Humph. You're configuring the same thing using the `InverseProperty` attribute and `HasOne`/`WithMany` calls in `OnModelCreating`. Same with the foreign key configuration. Maybe try removing the attribute it doesn't like, since its work is already done?

Comment: @SNBS Commenting out the InverseProperty and/or the modelBuilder.Entity definitions made no difference.  Same error

Comment: What's the error message? Do you mean it still points to (now non-existent) attribute `InverseProperty`?

Comment: I commented out the InverseProperty attribute (left property definitions intact) as well as the modelBuilder definition.  It appears by-convention, the relationship is still being inferred as it's the exact the same error message as in the OP.  Updated OP to how it looks now.

Comment: This suddenly came to my mind: `ICollection<Question>` instead of `ICollection<MapQuestion>`. Indeed, you store `Question` entities in the database and not `MapQuestion`s. To access `MapQuestion` properties, you'll have to use a cast. If it works, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference.  Since this doesn't make any sense, I'm going to strip down the model to a minimum repro case and work it from there with MS.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: The last thing I have to suggest is removing `abstract` from the `Question` definition.